# How to complete one full execution of all the thread in test plan before starting another instead of running each thread X number of times

Tags: loops, jmeter

[image]In my TestPlan in jmeter I have around 50 thread group and I want to run those multiple times but 2nd iteration should only start when all the 50 threads are executed once.

There is a loop count field in jmeter but it do not solve my problem instead it runs each thread X number of times before start executing next thread.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put all the transaction/Request under one thread group and no. of threads as 1 and control iteration with loop count. Since, you want to execute only once and in sequence. Though, it is not the exact answer but another way to doing it.
 [image]

Comment: Actaully @sunny_teo its not the answer i am looking for. I want when all threads are individually present.   Another way to do it is by using "include controller" but its kinda same as what you have suggested and it works much better. Thanks for helping.:)

Comment: Can you share your plan/sample plan to understand it further. May be it help others to give quick response.

Comment: So @sunny_teo as you can see I have 7 threads here and i want to run them all once before continuing with the 2nd iteration of all threads. Like this 5 times.

Comment: I think it is not possible. Either thread group runs in parallel or in sequence.

Comment: i dont know if possible or not. let C if someone has found some workaround or something that could help.

Comment: Yes, I mean it is not straight away possible, but somebody might give you some approach.